# Rails Date Query for setting Expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a marketplace app where sellers can list items to sell. I want to set an expiry date so listings over 30 days old do not show on the site.

I found some similar examples online but can't get this query to work.

```
@listings = Listing.where('created_at <= ?', Date.created_at + 30.day)
```

Comment: Try `@listings = Listing.where('created_at <= ?', Time.now - 30.day)`

Comment: I get the error `undefined method ``created_at' for Date:Class`. Created_at is a column that is auto generated by rails when a listing is created.

Comment: Please check the answer below, I made a little mistake in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to query items whose `created_at` time is `>=` the current date (`Date.current`) - 30 days (`30.day`). So the query should simply be:

```
@listings = Listing.where('created_at >= ?', Date.current - 30.day)
```

You can also replace `Date.current` with `Time.now` or `DateTime.now`.

**UPDATE:** as **user3334690** mentioned in a comment, it's recommended that you make this a model method since it's something that should be in the Model layer:

```
# app/models/listing.rb
def self.not_expired
    where('created_at >= ?', Date.current - 30.day)
end

# now in controllers you can do something like
@listings = Listing.not_expired
```

Comment: I would suggest making it a scope on the Listing model though... something like current or relevant or even not_expired

Comment: @user3334690 you mean a model method?

Comment: How do I put the same not_expired method into an if statement? The above code lets me filter results on the index pages. But if I want to put an expired message on listing show pages, can I enter an if statement into the `def show` method?